# Can't Install pulseaudio

Tags: kali-linux, pulseaudio, pulseaudio-equalizer

```
#apt-get install pulseaudio


Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have 
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable 
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created 
or been moved out of Incoming. 
The following information may help to resolve the situation: 

The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
pulseaudio : Depends: libpulse0 (= 13.0-3) but 13.0-5 is to be installed 
             Depends: pulseaudio-utils but it is not going to be installed 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http.kali.org/kali kali-last-snapshot main non-free contrib 
deb http.kali.org/kali kali-experimental main non-free contrib 
deb-src  http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Comment: Welcome, What is your linux distro? Could you add the content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-last-snapshot main non-free contrib
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-experimental main non-free contrib
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem come from `kali-experimental` and `kali-last-snapshot` in your sources.list.

On kali linux switching branches doesn't cause a problem but mixing will do.

> You may have **multiple branches enabled at once**. However, switching branches may introduce problems, as packages may be at different versions, and unavailable or unstable in certain cases.

To solve this problem you need to use only one kali-linux branch, three choices (explained on kali-linux docs : Debian’s Relation):

## `kali-rolling` (Default & frequently updated)

​
Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` should contain only:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

You can use the following command :

```
echo "deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
```

## `kali-last-snapshot` (debian stable equivalent)

Your /etc/apt/sources.list should contain only:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-last-snapshot main non-free contrib
```

command line:

```
echo "deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-last-snapshot main non-free contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
```

## `kali-experimental` (Packages which are under testing - often used with the rolling repository) ​

Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` may contain only:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-experimental main non-free contrib
```

command line:

```
echo "deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-experimental main non-free contrib" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Once done, run the following command:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

[Kali Branches](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/kali-branches/)

[Kali Network Repositories (/etc/apt/sources.list)](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/)

[Sudo on kali-linux?](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/sudo/)

Answer (score 2):

When it says you've held broken packages you can use:

```
dpkg -l | grep "^hi"
```

To find them.  What to do about them is your choice and depends on why they're being held.

Held packages means that for some reason, either manually or policy or what have you, those packages are set to a specific version. If you don't need them at that version you can stop holding them and do a full upgrade/update and get pulse installed.