# E: Unable to locate package python-pip on Kali Linux

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux

I'm trying to install the package python-pip on Kali Linux, but when I try, with `sudo apt-install python-pip`) it tells me "E: Unable to locate package python-pip".
I'm not sure what to do; I've tried every common solution but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please execute the commands below:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
```

Answer (score 2):

The `python-pip` package is only available for `kali-last-snapshot` branch  (stable). To install it through `apt` (with the exact name `python-pip`) you need to switch branch to `kali-last-snapshot` , [see this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/579166/153195).

On `kali-rolling` you need to install `python3-pip` package.

kali: [python-pip](http://http.kali.org/pool/main/p/python-pip/)

Comment: Is there a reason why?

Answer (score 0):

People running Kali Linux need to give command `sudo apt install python3-pip` it will fulfill all the dependencies.